# Is it safe to write an unsigned byte array in network order directly to ip.ip_dest?

Tags: c, networking, ip

In netinet/ip.h there is struct "ip" which is used to transmit IP packets. The address fields are "ip_src"  and "ip_dest".

If I have my IPv4 addresses in network order in an unsigned byte array, am I safe copying this array directly to ip_src and ip_dest?

For example, if I am sending a packet to 23.45.167.92 and I have the following unsigned char[4]:

```
destination_ip[0] = 23;
destination_ip[1] = 45;
destination_ip[2] = 167;
destination_ip[3] = 92;
```

Can I then safely do this:

```
struct ip my_packet_header;
my_packet_header.ip_dest = *((ip_addr*)destination_ip);
```

By "safely" I mean it will work on both big endian and little endian machines.

Comment: what is **ip_addr**?

Comment: `memcpy()` would be more appropiate, IMHO (avoiding the cast and the alignment woes)

Comment: It will be the address of destination_ip instead of the bytes in it.

Answer (score 0):

from [`man ip`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)

> The `s_addr` member of `struct in_addr`
>          contains the host interface address in network byte order.

So you are ok copying bytes, but it's better to use a memcpy instead of the cast.

```
memcpy(&my_packet_header.ip_dest.s_addr, destination_ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from endian, at least one concern exists: Alignment.

`struct ip my_packet_header` may have a more stringent alignment requirement than `unsigned char destination_ip[]`

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned  for the referenced type, the **behavior is
>   undefined**.   C11 §6.3.2.3 7

---

`memcpy()` handles that issue and eliminates woes [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337139/is-it-safe-to-write-an-unsigned-byte-array-in-network-order-directly-to-ip-ip-de/54339967#comment95491759_54337139)

```
assert(sizeof my_packet_header >= sizeof destination_ip);
memcpy(&my_packet_header, destination_ip, sizeof destination_ip);
```

An optimizing compiler can be expected to analyze this `memcpy()` call and emit efficient code - possible without a true function call.